# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Ajax.Begin Form gives extra line on top System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

Is this correct way to create a Ajax Form in ASP.Net MVC 3.0

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", null, new AjaxOptions
            {UpdateTargetId = "dialog-model", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            }, new { id ="AjaxForm" })

<input class="product-search" id="txtSearchProduct" name="SearchString" type="text" />
<input type="submit" id="AjaxForm" class="button", value="Search"/>

<div id="searchResults">
@Html.Raw((string)ViewBag.TotalList)<br />
<br />
@Html.Raw(ViewData["MarkupSearch"].ToString())
</div>
```

This works perfectly as needed but give an extra line on the view as

```
**System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm**
```

can any one help me in this, how I can remove that extra line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enclose your form in a using structure.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", null, new AjaxOptions
            {UpdateTargetId = "dialog-model", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            }, new { id ="AjaxForm" }))
{
...form here
}
```